# Has App Store download size limit over Cellular data changed from 150 MB in iOS 12?

Tags: ios

I downloaded a 200 MB app over Cellular data today. Then I tried another 300 MB app, with no warnings whatsoever, and the download completed successfully. Final I tried a 1.2 GB download which failed with the popup warning message.

I understand that [App Slicing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1795/_index.html) has appeared since iOS 9. The actual download size is different from the indicated size. But after downloading, I checked in Setting app → General → → iPhone Storage, and the two apps are over 150 MB(198 MB and 211 MB). And they are new download not updates.

Is the size displayed incorrectly or has the upper cap for downloading new apps over Cellular data changed?

PS:I downloaded that two app before but uninstalled it.
Another assumption is that the downloaded content is actually less than 150 MB but there is a process of decompression?

Comment: Can you check if the date and time are correctly set on your iPhone?

Comment: @NimeshNeema  Time and date are automatically adjusted and correct

Comment: The size shown on the App Store page is the download size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed my own conjecture,the downloaded content is actually less than 150 MB.

My test object is [bilibili-blue](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/%E5%93%94%E5%93%A9%E5%93%94%E5%93%A9%E6%A6%82%E5%BF%B5/id1204090346)
First of all, the size shown in the APP Store is 224.2 MB
[image]

After downloading,In Settings app → General → iPhone Storage shows App Size 224MB

[image]

I use a vpn application name shadowrocket to check traffic,it shows that the usage is 131.3 MB.

[image]

Then I use [charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to confirm,it gives the result that the actual download size is less than 150 MB(130.63).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**No**. The upper cap for downloading new apps over mobile data connection is unchanged from Apple. It's still at 150 MB. There is no official word from Apple after last revising the upper cap to 150 MB. This is the warning that I get (Indian App Store, accessing over 3G data connection in India) when attempting to download an app of size 2 GB.

[image]

However, the related Apple support document, [If you can’t download or update apps, or if apps get stuck](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207165) mentions the following in fine print.

> #### Connect to Wi-Fi
>
> If you’re using cellular data or Wi-Fi and have issues with an app, try to [connect to another Wi-Fi network](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202639). You can use cellular data for apps up to 150 MB* in size.
>
> #### Get more help
>
> If you still have issues with apps on your device, [contact Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/contact).
>
> *Depending on your country or region, and your carrier, the download limit might be higher.

The restriction is in place not due to some limitations in iOS, but to guard the mobile service providers network against congestions. From the statement it appears that some service providers must have worked with Apple and are offering a higher download size cap.